# Source Depot Browser / Set External Diff

Tags: source-depot

Source Depot is a Microsoft version-control utility.

Source Depot Browser is a GUI client for Source Depot (similar to Tortoise SVN being a GUI client for SVN).

The default diff tool is Win-Diff, and I would like to change Source Depot Browser to use Beyond Compare.

This is as far as I've reached:

- Open the 'Tools' menu
- Choose the 'SDB Options' option
- Switch to the 'View/Diff' tab
- Mark the 'Use external diff' check-box

There doesn't seem to be any browsing-button that allows you to choose the actual diff application.

Now, when I hover above the 'Use external diff' check-box, it tells me 'Only takes effect if SDDIFF or SDUDIFF is defined'. So I tried to define SDDIFF as an environment variable, setting it to the full path of Beyond Compare. I then closed Source Depot Browser and reopened it, but no luck. The only difference is, that instead of Win-Diff being invoked, nothing at all seems to be invoked (which might indicate that my environment variable definition is incorrect).

Any thoughts or ideas on how to make it work would be highly appreciated.

**UPDATE:**

1. I am using Windows Server 2012 / 64-bit
2. I defined a system variable SDDIFF as "C:\Program Files (x86)\Beyond Compare 2\BC2.exe"

Comment: Is your machine a x86 or x64 machine? Could you list the value you set in environment variable?

Answer (score 2):

Did you enclosed Beyond Compare's full path with double quotation marks?

```
SDDIFF="C:\Program Files\Beyond Compare 2\BC2.exe"
```

Comment: Yes I did. Sorry for not mentioning that (I probably should have, as I did mention my suspicion of the environment variable definition being incorrect). Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to successfully change my default diff tool using Barak manos's notes above. I closed sdb and the command prompt after adding the "sddiff" environment variable with the full path of beyond compare exe. The next time I opened sdb and compared code to server, it used Beyond Compare instead of Windiff.